# No element found in ajax

Tags: jquery, post

I'm making an Ajax call to an api to do something on the server. The problem is that I got the error `no element found` whether the action is successful or not
Here's the Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url : "test",
    type: "POST",
    data : {id:myid},
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        //data - response from server
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that jQuery assumes that the response format is xml.

You should add the `dataType` option.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Yep that did it

Comment: Thanks for the answer